# Nested Select Query works in PostgreSQL but not MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

The below nested SELECT query works in PostgreSQL but not MySQL and I can't figure out why:

```
INSERT INTO
    employees(
        id,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        job_title,
        base_salary,
        commission_pct
    )
VALUES
    (
        400,
        'Elise',
        'Ryan',
        'Auditing Clerk',
        (
            SELECT
                MAX(base_salary)
            FROM
                employees
            WHERE
                job_title = 'Auditing Clerk'
        ),
        (
            SELECT
                AVG(commission_pct)
            FROM
                employees
            WHERE
                job_title = 'Auditing Clerk'
        )
    )
```

Below is the error message MySQL gives me

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'employees' for update in FROM clause**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work in both :

```
INSERT INTO
    employees(
        id,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        job_title,
        base_salary,
        commission_pct
    )
SELECT
    400,
    'Elise',
    'Ryan',
    'Auditing Clerk',
    MAX(base_salary),
    AVG(commission_pct)
FROM
    employees
WHERE
    job_title = 'Auditing Clerk'
```

Comment: Thank you! It now works in both databases.